# Is it possible to Take object members directly from a queue of type object?

Tags: c#, queue

If I where to have a Queue holding a collection of objects (Custom object,bool,bool,bool,bool)
and the custom object holds three doubles itself.

Can I use the `.Take(IntegerValue)` command to only take **one** of the doubles (for the specified take length) from the custom entity contained in the queue and cast it to a double array, possibly with the `.ToArray<double>` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom object contains a double array, then you can do something like this:

```
queue.OfType<CustomObject>().Select(o => o.doubleArray[0]).Take(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queue.Select(o => o.Member).Take(integerValue).ToArray();
```